# A very simple stats question regarding the relative likelihood of certain combinations of rugby injuries

Tags: statistics

I’m a sports blogger, working up an article for a rugby website. It’s about the likelihood of combinations of injuries in the forthcoming world cup.

A rugby squad of 33 players includes two hookers (not sex workers, but a rugby position, like an NFL center, but uglier) and five props (uglier again).

These seven players are collectively called front rowers.

If a total of one player is injured every ten games, what are the chances of both hookers being seriously injured in one game?

What are the chances of any two props being injured in one game?

What are the chances of any two front rowers being injured in one game?

I appreciate that these are idiotically simple questions, but I’m an idiot.

Thanks maths dudes.

Kitou

Comment: two hookers are you talking about wales ;)? also I would not attribute a hooker to a tightend (they are more second rowers/flankers even athletic etc) I would say more like centers - squat, powerful and right in the middle!

Comment: Wales and Australia, Chinny84.

Comment: Can you clarify what the rates of injury are for the different types of players - is it really the same for all players regardless of playing position?

Comment: Hi David, I don't have that information, so this is a simplified example. One player being injured every ten games is an assumption. For this example, it's also assumed that all players are equally likely to be injured. I accept that this isn't the case in the real world. The real issue I'm exploring here is players being injured in the 48 hour replacement window, which includes training injuries. That seems to happen in about 1 in 10 professional games.

Comment: Please add this information to your question

Answer (score 0):

From what you say, I deduce that the probability any one front rower will get injured in a game is $p = 1/70$. You say the injury rate is $\lambda_7 = 1/10$ per game for all 7 players, so it's $\lambda = 1/70$ per game per player. Then for the number of injuries
per player per game its $Y \sim Pois(\lambda)$ and 
$p = P(Y = 1) = 0.0141 \approx 1/70.$

I am assuming injuries occur independently. Roughly, that means one injury in a game does not help trigger or prevent another. Perhaps not strictly true, but I know of no way to solve the problems otherwise.

Then the number of hookers injured per game is $X_H \sim Binom(2, p)$ and we want $$P(X_H = 2) = p^2 \approx 0.0002.$$

The number of props injured in a game is $X_P \sim Binom(5, p)$
and we want 
$$P(X_P \ge 2) = \sum_{k=2}^5 {5 \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{5-k} =  0.0020.$$
(I take it that you think two such injuries per game is worth
remarking on, so even more so for two or more: for exactly two it
also rounds to 0.0020.)

The number of front rowers injured in a game is $X_F \sim Binom(7, p)$
and we want 
$$P(X_F \ge 2) = \sum_{k=2}^7 {7 \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{5-k} =  0.0041.$$
(For exactly two, 0.0040.)

I did the computations using R statistical software, the 
computational session is printed below in case you want more
decimal places.

```
 dbinom(2, 2, 1/70)
 ## 0.0002040816
 sum(dbinom(2:5, 5, 1/70))
 ## 0.001983130
 dbinom(2, 5, 1/70)
 ## 0.001954596
 sum(dbinom(2:7, 7, 1/70))
 ## 0.004085956
 dbinom(2, 7, 1/70)
 ## 0.003988214
```

Please leave a comment if you think I have misinterpreted anything.

Note: I suspect you may have an instance in which the number of
injuries in a particular game was large, and that you suspect
something beyond chance may have been going on. However, if you
are focusing one game from among hundreds, then you should tell
me $that$ story, because that might require another computation
entirely.